# Pythons sleep-function not behaving as expected when called from Express-server

Tags: python, express, sleep

I'm calling a python-script from my express-server like this;

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
py    = spawn('python', ['test.py']);
```

In that script i log sensordata every 60 min (3600 sec) in a infinite while loop.

```
while True:
  //do my thing
  time.sleep(3600)
```

The first 2 or iterations the script logs correctly (every hour), after that it starts to log every 40 minutes ish. What is happening here? Are there better ways to log data periodically?

EDIT: 
The console.log for each iteration is provided below. After some research i think the problem is with the sleep()-function.

13:52:30
 13
 13:27:38
 14
 12:52:25
 14
 12:27:33
 12
 11:52:20
 15
 11:27:27
 12
 10:52:15
 14
 10:27:21
 13
 09:27:16
 11
 08:27:10

The while-loop in my program. Excluded the helpers to reduse the code.

```
while True:
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  t1 = sense.get_temperature_from_humidity()
  t2 = sense.get_temperature_from_pressure()
  t_cpu = get_cpu_temp()
  h = sense.get_humidity()
  p = sense.get_pressure()


  t = (t1+t2)/2
  t_corr = t - ((t_cpu-t)/1.5)
  t_corr = get_smooth(t_corr)
  #database
  db = MySQLdb.connect(***************************)
  curs=db.cursor()

  curs.execute("""INSERT INTO weatherdata(date,time,temperature,pressure,humidity) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(now,datetime.datetime.now().time(),t_corr,p,h))
  db.commit()
  print "Data committed"

  time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: As stated, this seems improbable, Is it possible to provide a little more information perhaps some debug log messages which may shine some light on the situation?

Comment: After the first three iterations, It appears as though the results are still coming every hour (27 minutes after the hour) but then results are also being generated at 52 minutes after the hour. It's almost like two copies of the script/thread/process are running in parallel just offset.

Comment: Yes. I can agree. Is there a reason for that? Maybe it's the thread the server creates to execute the script?

Comment: I cannot know for sure, but in my experience the Python sleep function is very reliable. If this were a bug of mine it would probably be in the logic around spawning the process. Is there a possible code-path you can spot which could lead to spawn being called twice?

Comment: Although I'm less experienced in JS than Python, it seems strange to me to have a comma ending a line is that a typo (ie should it be a semi-colon?), more importantly is that how the code is written or is it a typo on this post or is it intentional?

Comment: It's a typo! edited

Comment: The server is very straight forward. so it should'nt be anything happening there. I will have a look at that spawn function

Comment: Output buffering inside Python?

Comment: I'm not sure? I'm very inexperienced with python. I'll post the code.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the Python code, fairly straight-forward. This should indeed pause for one hour between runs. output buffering would not cause this, I think, because it would not affect the timestamps it would just affect when you see the timestamp printed to the screen.

Comment: What do the integers in between the timestamps in the log messages represent?

Comment: Just the data. Temperature ;) .. Allright, so i guess it's the function that spawns the child-process..

Comment: If there is a possibility that the function spawning the child process might be called twice. That would explain the behavior.

Comment: It's not really.. the only code on the server is basically the code provided. Apart from the server listening on port and serves data from get("/"). Really weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150643/discussion-between-ilovetux-and-kimr).